# How to direct a user to the record when he click on record number?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I have a record table. I want to make product brief number clickable. When user click on the product brief number it will take to the record (open the product brief). Does anybody have idea? Thanks
[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" extensions="DispatcherContactNewController">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbs}" var="p">
            <tr class="lnkdsble" ><apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/></tr>
            <apex:column value="{!p.RecordTypeId}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!p.Createddate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
        </apex:panelGrid>
     </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
    public class DispatcherContactNewController {

        public DispatcherContactNewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        public ApexPages.StandardSetController setpb {
            get{
                if (setpb == null) {
                    setpb = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                        [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, Createddate FROM Product_Brief__c])
                                                               );
                }
                return setpb;
            }
            set;
        }

        public List<Product_Brief__c>getpbs() {
            return (List<Product_Brief__c>)setpb.getrecords();
        }

        public Boolean hasNext {
            get {
                return setpb.getHasNext();
            }
            set;
        }

        public Boolean hasPrevious {
            get {
                return setpb.getHasPrevious();
            }
            set;
        }

        public Integer pageNumber {
            get {
                return setpb.getPageNumber();
            }
            set;
        }

        public void first() {
            setpb.first();
        }

        public void last() {
            setpb.last();
        }


        public void previous() {
            setpb.previous();
        }


        public void next() {
            setpb.next();
        }
    }
```

**Code**

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="Recent Product Briefs">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbs}" var="p" >
        <apex:column > 
            <apex:facet name="header">Product Brief Number</apex:facet>
            <a href="/{!p.Id}" id="{!p.Id}" target="_blank"
                   onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}').hide();" 
                   onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!p.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
                   onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}').hide();" 
                   onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!p.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!p.Name}</a>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!p.RecordTypeId}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!p.Createddate}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: See e.g. [Link List of records to detail using visualforce & apex](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78086/link-list-of-records-to-detail-using-visualforce-apex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!p.Id}"> {!p.Name} </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

instead of this

```
<apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
```

By doing this you'll be generating a link within the column to /(YourRecordId) which will be your record, while retaining the record name for the user to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can also retrieve a hover mini page layout of the object like this :

```
<a href="/{!p.Id}" id="{!p.Id}" target="_blank"
           onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}').hide();" 
           onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!p.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
           onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}').hide();" 
           onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!p.Id}', '/{!p.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!p.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">
           {!p.Name}</a>
```

This can be helpful if you want to display additional fields on hover.

Comment: Its work and really nice. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey, Its work fine but do you know why it does not wok when i click on the link? (When hover over it has a button called view. It works fine but when  you click one the link before hover over it will break the page. Any idea thanks )

Comment: the link should work as well you have it in your href=""...if you share your code I can be more specific...but if it doesn't maybe try to add onclick="/{p.Id}" event..

Comment: Hi Yuval, Thanks For helping me out. I added a code section for more details. I try to add onclick="/{p.Id}". Still the same case, when i click on the link it does not work. Thanks

Comment: sorry..seems like everything is in order - it worked for me.. :)